# Retrieving rows via PYODBC

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm having some issues right now with my code. On one hand, I have code that works, but I think I can improve upon. However my attempt to refine the code have been...disastrous. Here is my original code:

```
overall_list = []
customer_list = []
if remote_system_id == 'hibiscus' or remote_system_id is None:
    hibiscus_cursor.execute(hibiscus_full_SQLstring, hibiscus_parameters)
    row = hibiscus_cursor.fetchone()
    resultCounter = 0
    while row and resultCounter < remote_system_max_results:
        customer_list.append({'Hibiscus Customer Number': str(row[0])})
        row = hibiscus_cursor.fetchone()
        resultCounter += 1
    overall_list.append(customer_list)

customer_list = []
if remote_system_id == 'coxcomb' or remote_system_id is None:
    coxcomb_cursor.execute(coxcomb_full_SQLstring, coxcomb_parameters)
    row = coxcomb_cursor.fetchone()
    resultCounter = 0
    while row and resultCounter < remote_system_max_results:
        customer_list.append({'Coxcomb Customer Number': str(row[0])})
        row = coxcomb_cursor.fetchone()
        resultCounter += 1
    overall_list.append(customer_list)
```

The above is code that works, but I've been told to refine it a bit more. Specifically, that I have two separate routines for generating the output. I was told to combine it, but results have not been favorable:

```
customer_list = []
hibiscus_cursor.execute(hibiscus_full_SQLstring, hibiscus_parameters)
coxcomb_cursor.execute(coxcomb_full_SQLstring, coxcomb_parameters)
row = coxcomb_cursor.fetchone()
resultCounter = 0
while row and resultCounter < remote_system_max_results:
    customer_list.append({'Hibiscus Customer Number': str(row[0])})
    row = coxcomb_cursor.fetchone()
    customer_list.append({'Coxcomb Customer Number': str(row[0])})
    row = hibiscus_cursor.fetchone()
    resultCounter += 1
```

The code above is my attempt to refine it, but with no good results. Any ideas on why I get an error like this:

```
customer_list.append({'Coxcomb Customer Number': str(row[0])})
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

EDIT:

A bit more info. These are two separate databases, and not at all related to each other. Their only probable relation is that they both contain customer information. Connected like this:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(HIBISCUS_CONNECTION)
hibiscus_cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(COXCOMB_CONNECTION)
coxcomb_cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

I'm querying both databases, and I'm hoping to find something like:

```
WHERE firstname LIKE 'adam'
```

In the first code, it works perfectly fine. In the second one, I get the error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by making these changes:

```
customer_list = []
hibiscus_cursor.execute(hibiscus_full_SQLstring, hibiscus_parameters)
coxcomb_cursor.execute(coxcomb_full_SQLstring, coxcomb_parameters)
row = hibiscus_cursor.fetchone()
row2 = coxcomb_cursor.fetchone()
resultCounter = 0
while (row or row2) and resultCounter < remote_system_max_results:
    if hibiscus_cursor.fetchone() is not None:
        customer_list.append(str(row[0]))
        row = hibiscus_cursor.fetchone()
    if coxcomb_cursor.fetchone() is not None:
        customer_list.append(str(row2[0]))
        row2 = coxcomb_cursor.fetchone()
    resultCounter += 1
```

Code is inefficient. May not be useful.